# Get bounding rectangle of children in a Stack widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Let us consider a Stack having a few child widgets. The child widgets have some `transform` applied to them.

How do we determine the smallest bounding Rect which contains all the children?

```
    Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          left: 20,
          right: 20,
          child: Container(
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            transform: transform,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 80,
          right: 100,
          child: Container(
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            transform: transform,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 30,
          right: 10,
          child: Container(width: 50, height: 50),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: do you have to use `Stack`? with `Flow` you would do that without any problems

Comment: I don't have to use `Stack`, how would I achieve this with flow?

Comment: inside a custom `FlowDelegate` you need to call `MatrixUtils.transformRect` on every child